# How to clone git repository using ansible under microsoft windows

Tags: windows, git, ansible

Ansible 2.1, control host under centos7, number of windows 10 as clients.

I need to clone git reposritory on remote side, but no idea how to do this:

- there is no [windows native module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/list_of_windows_modules.html)
- [linux module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/git_module.html) doesn't work

I've tried something like:

```
- name: clone repositories
  git:
   repo: "{{ item.repo }}"
   dest: "C:\openserver\domains\{{ domain_name }}\{{ item.value.path }}"
   version: "{{ item.version | default('HEAD') }}"
  with_items: "{{ repositories }}"
```

Comment: You'll probably need to run git in windows powershell as described in http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_windows.html

Comment: [msw](http://stackoverflow.com/users/282912/msw) is right - the usage of "normal" Ansible modules like [git](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/git_module.html) for managing Windows boxes isn´t possible. As there´s no git module for now in the [windows modules](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/list_of_windows_modules.html), you have to improvise with powershell scripts and/or the raw module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found `win_git` module to use from @tivrobo:

https://github.com/tivrobo/ansible-win_git

Answer (score 2):

if not too late, you can use something like this

```
- name: clone repositories
  win_command: >
    "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe"
    "--no-pager"
    "clone"
    "http://user:pass@github.com/OpenCorpora/opencorpora.git"
    "C:\OPenserver\domains\opencorpora.local\www"
    "--branch"
    "master"
    "--recursive"
```

reference https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_usage.html

Comment: What sucks is this solution only works once, it breaks if the repo already cloned.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible [recommends](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_windows.html#what-modules-are-available) to use [script](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/script_module.html) module, i used [raw](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/raw_module.html) module instead (is this way less secure than script module?):

```
- name: clone repositories
  raw: C:\OpenServer\modules\git\cmd\git.exe clone https://github.com/OpenCorpora/opencorpora.git C:\OPenserver\domains\opencorpora.local\www
```

Prerequirements: msysgit installed (`C:\OpenServer\modules\git\` in my case ), or native git client for windows (see here: https://git-scm.com/download/win)

PS Unfortunately, i don't know today how to use native client with *default* install path (with whitespaces):

```
- name: clone repositories
  raw: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe clone https://github.com/OpenCorpora/opencorpora.git C:\OPenserver\domains\opencorpora.local\www
```

It fails with error:

```
TASK [website_win : clone repositories] ****************************************
fatal: [192.168.1.43]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "rc": 1, "stderr": "C:\\Program : The term 'C:\\Program' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable progra\r\nm. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.\r\nAt line:1 char:1\r\n+ C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd\\git.exe clone https://github.com/OpenCorpora ...\r\n+ ~~~~~~~~~~\r\n+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\\Program:String) [], CommandNotFoundException\r\n+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException\r\n", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************
```

Comment: Still there is an issue with SSH protocol and SSL key, here is details: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/NjND8LYqHnQ

Comment: The error seems related to your usage of the raw module. Try to use quotes and escape all backslashes: `raw: C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd\\git.exe clone https://github.com/OpenCorpora/opencorpora.git`