# Ansible win_shell hangs in git pull

Tags: linux, git, ansible, devops

I am using win_shell module to remotely execute a "git pull" command,
But it hangs and no returning values to the terminal.

My play book

```
- name: connect to web server 1
  hosts: windows

  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  #  - name: execute git pull
    - win_shell: git pull
      args:
        executable: cmd
        chdir : c:\inetpub\wwwroot\sa.local
```

it hangs on the terminal as below.

```
TASK [win_shell] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/windows/group_vars/sa.yml:7
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/windows/win_shell.ps1
<192.168.122.53> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: administrator on PORT 5986 TO 192.168.122.53
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
```

really appreciate your help here.

Comment: You should look at this very close question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39301265/how-to-clone-git-repository-using-ansible-under-microsoft-windows

Comment: @Romain this works in windows server 2012, issue with 2016 only